# Terminate a process from another process

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I am trying to make an LCD display to display both the current temperature and the humidity at the same time in different lines. I have a sample code as below. The problem is that when the temperature goes above say 50C, I want the humidity reading to stop as well. I have 2 thread running at the same time, reading from both sensors.

```
#all important imports are here

 def main():

    # Very simplified code, not actual.

    tempP = Process(target=temperature)
    humidP = Process(target=humidity)

    tempP.start()
    humidP.start()

 def temperature():

    while True:
       #ADC printing to LCD code is here
        temperatureReading = ADC.channel(0)
       if temperatureReading > 50:
          humidP.terminate() # Does not work, I still see the humidity on
```

the screen with overlapping characters

Comment: Can you show us where is `temperatureReading` calculated? Also are you sure that it ever goes over 50?

Comment: temperatureReading is the sensor reading from the ADC. So after each reading, it check if its > 50C, if not it prints to LCD. Yes even if I hardcode the reading to 60C, the terminate() does not work